# Error inflating class fragment using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am getting `Error inflating class fragment` on Binary XML while using the google Map fragment inside activity. I have searched many similar problem here in this forum but still it is not working.I have put keys in my Manifest file as well but getting meta-data error as well in application tag. I am putting down my both codes:

**activity.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_Map"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

</application>
```

**Inside Activity.java**

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

**Error Logs:**

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #379: Binary XML file line #379: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #379: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6587000 but found 10084000.  
You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: you must declare google_maps_key in your manifest

Comment: @ysl thanks for your reply. I did that change, but still i am getting this error. Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: you need to generate key for this

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup find this

Comment: @ysl, i already did that change here and enabled a Key from Google Console. But the error is same

Comment: you have to enter that integer value here  android:value="@string/google_maps_key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your logcat says :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6587000 but found 10084000.
```

Change google_play_services_version to 6587000.

Comment: Thanks alot. It works. I edited that values file for it.